# Rails 4 - Specify routes exclusively for development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Is it possible to create routes in Rails 4 that are only executed while the application is being run in dev mode?

Comment: try throwing those routes inside of `if Rails.env.development?` statement.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can test for the environment by the if statement:

```
 if Rails.env.development?
      #what you want in development
 end
```

You can put an else statement for other environment types.

This is similar to this question: [Changing a Rails route based on deployment type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521942/changing-a-rails-route-based-on-deployment-type)